# How to concat multiple pandas dataframes into one dask dataframe larger than memory?

Tags: pandas, hdf5, dask, pytables, bigdata

I am parsing tab-delimited data to create tabular data, which I would like to store in an HDF5.

My problem is I have to aggregate the data into one format, and then dump into HDF5. This is ~1 TB-sized data, so I naturally cannot fit this into RAM. Dask might be the best way to accomplish this task.

If I use parsing my data to fit into one pandas dataframe, I would do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv   

csv_columns = ["COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4",..., "COL55"]
readcsvfile = csv.reader(csvfile)

total_df = pd.DataFrame()    # create empty pandas DataFrame
for i, line in readcsvfile:
    # parse create dictionary of key:value pairs by table field:value, "dictionary_line"
    # save dictionary as pandas dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary_line, index=[i])  # one line tabular data 
    total_df = pd.concat([total_df, df])   # creates one big dataframe
```

Using dask to do the same task, it appears users should try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv 
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.array as da

csv_columns = ["COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4",..., "COL55"]   # define columns
readcsvfile = csv.reader(csvfile)       # read in file, if csv

# somehow define empty dask dataframe   total_df = dd.Dataframe()? 
for i, line in readcsvfile:
    # parse create dictionary of key:value pairs by table field:value, "dictionary_line"
    # save dictionary as pandas dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary_line, index=[i])  # one line tabular data 
    total_df = da.concatenate([total_df, df])   # creates one big dataframe
```

After creating a ~TB dataframe, I will save into hdf5.

My problem is that `total_df` does not fit into RAM, and must be saved to disk. Can `dask` dataframe accomplish this task?

Should I be trying something else? Would it be easier to create an HDF5 from multiple dask arrays, i.e. each column/field a dask array? Maybe partition the dataframes among several nodes and reduce at the end?

EDIT: For clarity, I am actually not reading directly from a csv file. I am aggregating, parsing, and formatting tabular data. So, `readcsvfile = csv.reader(csvfile)` is used above for clarity/brevity, but it's far more complicated than reading in a csv file.

Comment: Have you tried `dd.read_csv('filename.csv').to_hdf('filename.hdf5', '/df')`?

Comment: @MRocklin This only works (I believe) when importing from a csv file directly. If you are parsing csv rows, or tabular data from other sources, then this doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a reason why you choose to parse individual csv rows instead of using `dd.read_csv`?  The Pandas parser is much faster than the standard library `csv` module

Comment: @MRocklin It's not from a csv file. It's tab-delimited data I'm parsing into "csv-like" format. I simplified the question above somewhat for clarity. I should edit the above---you are right, the solution you have provided will work if using `csv.reader()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dask.dataframe handles larger-than-memory datasets through laziness.  Appending concrete data to a dask.dataframe will not be productive.

#### If your data can be handled by pd.read_csv

The [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function is very flexible.  You say above that your parsing process is very complex, but it might still be worth looking into the options for `pd.read_csv` to see if it will still work.  The `dask.dataframe.read_csv` function supports these same arguments.

In particular if the concern is that your data is separated by tabs rather than commas this isn't an issue at all. Pandas supports a `sep='\t'` keyword, along with a few dozen other options.

#### Consider dask.bag

If you want to operate on textfiles line-by-line then consider using dask.bag to parse your data, starting as a bunch of text.

```
import dask.bag as db
b = db.read_text('myfile.tsv', blocksize=10000000)  # break into 10MB chunks
records = b.str.split('\t').map(parse)
df = records.to_dataframe(columns=...)
```

#### Write to HDF5 file

Once you have dask.dataframe try the `.to_hdf` method:

```
df.to_hdf('myfile.hdf5', '/df')
```

Comment: What if I have a bag of dataframes ?